# Como fazer um count funcionar pegando somente os campos que eu quero?

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso pegar um campo que eu quero fazendo o `COUNT` funcionar?

```
select PVN.NFNum, COUNT(distinct CtrlCargaNum) as Qtd from CTRL_CARGA cc 
INNER JOIN PED_VENDA_NOTA_FISCAL PVN ON cc.EmpCod = PVN.EmpCod 
where cc.CtrlCargaData between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04' and cc.EmpCod = '01.01';
```

Dá o seguinte erro no `MySQL Server`:

> ```
> Column 'PED_VENDA_NOTA_FISCAL.NFNum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> ```

Comment: Você havia criado tópico semelhante e as respostas daquele tópico consideraram o que você havia informado por lá. Mas agora criou outro tópico, alterando um pouco a pergunta. A sugestão é que, quando perceber necessário, acrescente informações no tópico já existente, ao invés de ficar criando tópico novo à medida que se lembra de novo detalhe que não havia informado anteriormente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponha os campos que não são de agregação num `group by`:

```
select PVN.NFNum,
COUNT(distinct CtrlCargaNum) as Qtd from CTRL_CARGA cc 
INNER JOIN PED_VENDA_NOTA_FISCAL PVN ON cc.EmpCod = PVN.EmpCod 
where cc.CtrlCargaData between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'  
      and cc.EmpCod = '01.01'  
Group by PVN.NFNum;
```

Ou transforme os campos que não são de agregação em campos de agregação (max, min, avg..) (não recomendo):

```
select Max(PVN.NFNum) as NFNum,
COUNT(distinct CtrlCargaNum) as Qtd from CTRL_CARGA cc 
INNER JOIN PED_VENDA_NOTA_FISCAL PVN ON cc.EmpCod = PVN.EmpCod 
where cc.CtrlCargaData between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'  
      and cc.EmpCod = '01.01';
```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, como o `log` que você postou é preciso agrupar e para isso`group by`.

```
select PVN.NFNum, COUNT(distinct CtrlCargaNum) as Qtd from CTRL_CARGA cc INNER JOIN PED_VENDA_NOTA_FISCAL PVN ON cc.EmpCod = PVN.EmpCod where cc.CtrlCargaData between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04' and cc.EmpCod = '01.01' Group by PVN.NFNum
```

Um outra observação, como você está agrupando para realizar recuperar do `count` 
 por **PVN.NFNum** não é necessário utilizar o `distinct`, só fará com que sua query tenha um performance pior.